# What does this new icon tell me?

Tags: support

[image]

In my flags overview I found a new icon "active" - what should it tell me?

Comment: Check http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190738/213575 out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its an indicator to show that your flag is awaiting review. There's been quite a lot of backend moderation tools changes recently, and this is an extra as part of a few changes to flagging.